# Why did I not lose reputation when I deleted an upvoted answer?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, reputation

I deleted [an answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/85004/44937) that had 17 upvotes and 2 downvotes, but I didn't lose the 164 reputation I gained from that answer (9,051 rep before and after). Why not?

Comment: Related: [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/906208)

Comment: Why would you delete an upvoted answer?

Comment: @user16217248 it turned out that my answer was actually wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I lost the expected amount of rep. It looks like it just takes a few minutes.